# The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly - wcf

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, silverlight

I am using WCF Services in my WPF project.
I have a large amount of data, about 847000 records in table. this exception is throwed on client side

```
proxy.ServicesClient client = new proxy.ServicesClient();
var result = client.GetCustomers(); // here throws ('**ComunicationException was unhandled by user code**: *The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly*.')
```

In my app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
      <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
          <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IServices" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
              openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
              maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
            <security mode="None" />
          </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:5302/WpfStoreService.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IServices"
                contract="proxy.IServices" name="BasicHttpBinding_IServices" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

In Web.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AdventureWorksLTConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorksLT;Integrated Security=True" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>

        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IServices" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="52428899">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="128"
                        maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096"
                        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>

      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Did you have this problem on WCF Services?

Comment: there are timeouts in your config : isn't the issue occuring after those 10 minutes ?

Comment: No, this exception occurs during 30 - 40 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have overridden it somewhere else, the default DB Connection timeout will be a problem.

I think it can be disabled if you set the Connection Timeout value to 0, but this depends on the DbConnection implementation;

Try adding this to your Connection String.
`Connect Timeout=0`

`"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorksLT;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=0"`

Comment: thanks for replying, but not works :(
I notice that this exception occurs with large amount of data. If I decrease count of record for example to 1000 (now I have 847 000) it will work

Comment: Only one other really... Don't select 847000 records in one transaction. Instead focus your efforts on redesigning the interface to work with smaller chunks of data.

Comment: There is not problem retrieving records from SQL Server. I debuged it and whole this 847 000 record was retrieved without exception, on the server side. After wcf service calls this function rises that exception